# Centering a map element on a generated PDF

Tags: html, pdf

I'm working on a Symfony project where I need to generate PDF files from HTML templates that include a map element. However, I'm having trouble centering the map element on the PDF without using any specific PDF generation tools or libraries.

I have a Twig template called carte.html.twig that contains the map element. I want to position the map element in the center of the PDF page. I've tried adjusting the CSS styles within the template, but the map element doesn't appear centered on the generated PDF.

Here's a simplified snippet from my carte.html.twig template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        /* CSS styles for the map element */
        #map {
            /* Styles for the map */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map">
        <!-- Map content goes here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE6fU.jpg)

I'm seeking guidance on how to properly center the map element on the PDF generated from this Twig template without relying on any specific PDF generation tools or libraries. Are there any alternative approaches or techniques that I can use to achieve this?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with TWIG. Please tag accordingly